# la production est prévue d’ici la fin de l’année 2022

Tags: usage

Bonjour à tous,

Si cette phrase

```
La production est prévue d’ici la fin de l’année 2022.
```

se traduit en anglais comme

```
Production is scheduled for the end of 2022.
```

Je me demande :

1. à quoi sert `d'ici`
2. si on peut simplement dire `la production est prévue pour la fin de l'année 2022`?

Merci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En réalité, une traduction anglaise qui retransmet mieux le propos serait

> Production is scheduled to happen between now and the end of 2022.

Pour être précis, `d'ici` fait référence à l'instant présent. L'expression signifie donc que la production est prévue entre maintenant et 2022. Ce n'est donc pas exactement pareil que de dire "*La production est prévue pour la fin de l'année 2022*".

Une forme alternative (que je trouve plus claire à titre personnel) est d'utiliser *d'ici à*. **Il est important de noter que les deux formes sont admises.**

> La production est prévue d'ici à la fin de l'année 2022.

Avec cette forme, il est facile de comprendre l'utilité de *d'ici à*, qui peut être remplacé par *de maintenant à*.

Cependant, cette forme alternative donne également une impression de continuité, et me semble plus pertinente dans des contextes de type "*D'ici à l'année prochaine, je vais suivre des cours intensifs d'anglais*" (avis personnel).

Plus d'informations (et d'exemples) sont disponibles sur la sainte [banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3282).

Et, pour avoir une idée de l'usage préférentiel, voici [un exemple de ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&content=d%27ici%20demain%2C%20d%27ici%20%C3%A0%20demain&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%27%20ici%20demain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%27%20ici%20%C3%A0%20demain%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cd%27%20ici%20demain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%27%20ici%20%C3%A0%20demain%3B%2Cc0) qui compare la forme "d'ici demain" avec "d'ici à demain". À prendre avec des pincettes, comme toujours avec ngrams.

Comment: Il y a aussi l'expression dérivée *d'ici là* (ex: *je vais emmenager à Paris en décembre, mais d'ici là, je vis chez mes parents*)

Comment: Mais si tu as raison et que les 2 formules ne sont pas identiques, "d'ici" étant plus optimiste, en réalité même annoncé différemment les 2 ont souvent le même résultat...